# Button Text show uppercase letters in Android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

I created a blank app, I wrote the following code in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
    VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  
    LineBreakMode="MiddleTruncation" />

<Button x:Name="btn"  BorderColor="Teal"  
    Clicked="OnButtonClicked" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Test Click me" />
```

Then runs it, and there is an odd thing in the Android. The Label text shows right, but the button shows in uppercase letters "TEST CLICK ME". And I clicked the button let it shows its text property, it shows “Test Click me”.

Why is that?

Comment: <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" />
<Button x:Name="btn"  Clicked="OnButtonClicked" Text="Test Click me" />

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin forms : Button text always showing in uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545369/button-text-always-showing-in-uppercase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because by default, new Xamarin.Forms apps use Google Material Design, which specifies that button text should be capitalized if possible in that language.

> Button text should be capitalized in languages that have
>   capitalization.

That is from this page
https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#
which has the material design specification for buttons.