# Button text always showing in uppercase

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

In my xamarin forms project button text are always show in uppercase format.
But I am providing upper and lower case letters in xaml. When I build the solution all the letters are changed to uppercase.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm guessing you see this on Android as it is the default for button text and has been since Lollipop.

To change this behavior add the following to your styles.xml file which can be found in the Android project under the Resources then values folders

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

Comment: Yes I have just added above line in "MyTheme" style which was already there in styles.xml file.

<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

Comment: I have the same code in my project also, like: `<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base"><item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item></style>`. But its not working..!

Comment: I think this comment is the actual answer using the Button Property TextTransform https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11556#issuecomment-670677728

Comment: This is working for me using the exact code in RohitSharma's comment

Comment: This answer is outdated. Xamarin 4.8 introduced `TextTransform` which fixes the problem much more simply.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative is to simply use `TextTransform` property:

```
<Button Text="Click Me" TextTransform="None"/>
```

Or in a style definition:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="NoDefaultCapsButton">
     <Setter Property="TextTransform" Value="None"/>
</Style>

<Button Text="Click Me" Style="{x:StaticResource NoDefaultCapsButton}"/>
```

#### Important Note

Be sure you are using Xamarin.Forms NuGet package **4.8.0.1534** or above, if `TextTransform` is not showing for you than clean and rebuild your solution.

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this option? I am using Visual Studio Pro 2019 with a new  Xamarin.Forms project but there is no `TextTransform` option in either the Properties window of my `Button` or while trying to use a `<Setter Property="TextTransform" Value="None" />` in `App.xaml` > `ApplicationResources` > `<Style TargetType="Button">`. My Visual Studio is up-to-date.

Comment: @DannyBeckett https://i.stack.imgur.com/utqJt.png Which platform are you targeting? Maybe you are using an old version of Xamarin.Forms (I think it was introduced in 4.8).

Comment: My About page of VS is showing .NET as on v4.8.04084. Xamarin is on v16.7.000.463, Xamarin Designer is on v16.7.0.495, Xamarin Templates is on v16.7.85, Xamarin.Android SDK is on v11.0.2.0. My Shared project properties has the Target Framework as .NET *Standard* 2.0. The Android project properties has the Target Framework as Android 9.0 (Pie). The Android Manifest has the Minimum Android Version as Android 4.1 (API Level 16 - Jelly Bean). It has the Target Android Version as Android 9.0 (API Level 28 - Pie). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DannyBeckett When I updated Xamarin.Forms it complains with some warning in order to set the Target Framework to `Android Q 10.0`. This is the only difference between our used versions.

Comment: I've changed my Target Framework in both places to Android 10.0 (API Level 29 - Q) but still no joy unfortunately! Is your Minimum Android Version Android 4.1 (API Level 16 - Jelly Bean)? Thanks for trying.

Comment: @DannyBeckett no it is (Android 8.0 API Level 26). Which Xamarin.Forms NuGet package version are you using?

Comment: My Xamarin.Forms NuGet package was on 4.6.0.1141. I've updated it to 4.8.0.1560 and the TextTransform property is now available. I didn't need to modify the Minimum Android Version. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer assumes the user (even a newbie) to know which style the above code goes in. Even the comments below the accepted answer remain **unanswered**... I wonder why...

I just started learning Android Xamarin programming and I spent some good 20 mins to figure it out. For any users, **specially newbies**, see this example.

In your Android project, go to `Resources` > `values` > `styles.xml` and add:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/mybutton.text</item>
</style>

<style name="mybutton.text" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it has no effect. All I had to do was copy your text into the myapp.Android/Resources/values/styles.xml right ? Do I need to do some action before this kicks in ?

Comment: @GuidoG:  I stopped working on these long time ago. You may want to see other answers which were posted after mine and also cover latest versions?

Answer (score 7):

Recently I had the same issue even though I was using textAllCaps false in my styles.
It seems it doesn't work with prerlease version 4.8.0.1238-pre3 of Xamarin.Forms (latest available at the time of posting this). It does work with version 4.7.0.1239 of Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Agreed. The latest release of XF (4.8.0.1269) does not observer the textAllCaps false directive. I have reverted to 4.7.0.1260

Comment: Thanks, you saved me some fruitless searching for a fix

Comment: And here is an issue and a workaround to track progress : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11556 (apparently the fix is planned for vNext - 5.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for this issue that works for me in android and iOS for material to avoid automatic UpperCase conversion when **Visual** is set to "**Material**".

**Xamarin.Forms.Android:**

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**Xamarin.Forms.iOS:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(ButtonRendererEx), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace GettingStarted.iOS
{
    public class ButtonRendererEx : MaterialButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.UppercaseTitle = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `CustomRenderer` for this is an overkill I think, for Android part of the answer it is the same as [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545821/5228202)