# Xamarin Forms FontAwesome button text and normal text

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I want to create a button using fontawesome library in xamarin

[image: expected output] **(expected output)**

[image: this is mine] **(this is mine)**

```
<Button Text="&#xf104; Bireysel"
            TextColor="Black"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            FontSize="30"
            Margin="15,0,0,0"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

I wanna change text style how can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button text always showing in uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545369/button-text-always-showing-in-uppercase)

Comment: Would you mind providing a minimal sample via GitHub so I can help you test it. Thanks!

Comment: hi alexandar
Since this is a commercial project, it is not possible for me to share the source codes with you, but I have already specified the relevant piece of code in my question.

Comment: hi @Cfun
I am also experiencing the problem on IOS. When I examined the related question, I realized that there is a solution for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` can have both text and image with `FontImageSource`:

```
<Button Text="Left">
  <Button.ImageSource>
    <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xF104;"
                     FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" />
  </Button.ImageSource>
</Button>
```

Comment: where is the text "Bireysel" that the OP is expecting to see?

Comment: The text "Left" represents the name ("Angle Left") of the FontAwesome character with hex number F104

Answer (score 0):

Try this `TextTransform="None"`

```
<Button Text="&#xf104; Bireysel"
        TextColor="Black"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        FontSize="30"
        Margin="15,0,0,0"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        TextTransform="None"/>
```

Comment: it's still same :(